# 'Websocket is already in closing or closed state' when I have a javascript alert() open for around 30 seconds

Tags: websocket, socket.io, synchronous

I am using NodeJS server in the backend and angular soket.io-client for front end and communicating over websockets. When I have a javascript alert open in UI for around 30 seconds, 'Websocket is already in closing or closed state' error shows and the client is disconnected from server. I do not want this automatic disconnect to happen. Is there a work around to this to prevent the socket disconnect when a javascript alert() is open in the front end.